# Python. Selenium. Скрыть надпись 'Chrome for Testing v ___ is only for automated testing' в открывающемся окне браузера

Tags: python, selenium, браузер

Изучаю библиотеку selenium на python.
Не даёт покоя момент, можно ли как-то убрать надпись `Chrome for Testing v ___ is only for automated testing` в верхней части окна отрывающего браузера? Мозолит глаза и просто мешается.

```
from selenium import webdriver
with webdriver.Chrome() as browser:
    browser.get('https://ya.ru')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Удалите из заголовка "Python. Selenium.". Вы уже отметили предмет вопроса в метках.

Comment: да пусть будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
    op.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Этот код убирает другую надоедливую строчку "Chrome is being controlled by automated software..." , но не указанную мною :(

Comment: попробуй скачать другой хром и подсунуть его селениумуму

Comment: просто похожи строки... скопипастил у себя